# Keep two HTML forms on the same line in a paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a paragraph which has two seperate forms in it. However, when the page is loaded, there is a line break where each form starts. I am using the following code:

```
<p style="font-size:14px;font-weight:700;color:grey;">' . $user_pic . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $mem_id . '" style="color:#0F39C5;">' . $knockfirst . ' ' . $knocklast . '</a> is knocking. Let him in?
<form action="messages/group/addToChat.php" method="post" name="adduser"><input type="hidden" id="newid" name="newid" value="' . $mem_id . '"><input type="hidden" id="groupid" name="groupid" value="' . $group_id . '"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest(\'form\').submit(); return false;" style="color:#0F39C5;font-size:15px;">Yes</a></form>
<form action="messages/group/declineKnock.php" method="post" name="declineuser"><input type="hidden" id="newid" name="newid" value="' . $mem_id . '"><input type="hidden" id="groupid" name="groupid" value="' . $group_id . '"> | 
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest(\'form\').submit(); return false;" style="color:#0F39C5;font-size:15px;">No</a></form></p>
```

Is there any way to keep this all on the same line when it's rendered onto the page?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
form {
    display: inline-block; //Or display: inline; 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trW82/

Answer (score 6):

add `float` style to the first form -

```
style="float: left;"
```

better yet, create a separate CSS class -

```
.chatForm {
    float: left;
}
```

and assign this class to the first form -

```
<form class="chatForm" ......
```

You can also set `display` property of both form to either `inline` or `inline-block` -

```
.chatForm, .declineForm {
    display: inline-block; /* or inline */
}
```

and then -

```
<form class="chatForm" .....
<form class="declineForm" ....
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QQuT4/).

Check out the sitepoint reference on [**display**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display) and [**float**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/float).

Comment: The html doesn't require a "." to signify it's a class

Answer (score 0):

Give the forms a width (ie: style="width:300px") and then wrap each of the forms in a span tag

```
<p>
    <span><form style="width:300px;" /></span>
    <span><form style="width:300px;" /></span>
</p>
```

Failing that you can use the following style on the form:

```
<p>
    <form style="width:300px; display:inline-block;" />
    <form style="width:300px; display:inline-block;" />
</p>
```

Or you could try:

```
<p>
    <div style="width:300px; display:inline-block;"><form /></div>
    <div style="width:300px; display:inline-block;"><form /></div>
</p>
```

You may also want to move the style information into a CSS class definition for consistency.

There's always more than one way of doing things in HTML + CSS.

Good luck!

Comment: According to the HTML spec, neither `<form>` inside `<span>` nor `<div>` inside `<p>` is valid. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers here have pointed out the fact that your HTML is invalid in the first place. According to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-p-element), a `<p>` element cannot have a `<form>` as part of its content.

But since HTML is weird, there is still a way to have two forms inside the same (logical) paragraph, by not putting them in a `<p>`, but in a `<div>`, for example:

```
<div>
    <form style="display: inline;"><input type="submit" value="Submit 1"></form>
    <form style="display: inline;"><input type="submit" value="Submit 2"></form>
</div>
```

This is valid HTML [according to Nu HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%253C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%253E%250D%250A%253Chtml%2520lang%253D%2522%2522%253E%250D%250A%253Ctitle%253EForms%253C%252Ftitle%253E%250D%250A%253Cdiv%253E%250D%250A%253Cform%2520style%253D%2522display%253A%2520inline%253B%2522%253E%253Cinput%2520type%253D%2522submit%2522%2520value%253D%2522Submit%25201%2522%253E%253C%252Fform%253E%250D%250A%253Cform%2520style%253D%2522display%253A%2520inline%253B%2522%253E%253Cinput%2520type%253D%2522submit%2522%2520value%253D%2522Submit%25202%2522%253E%253C%252Fform%253E%250D%250A%253C%252Fdiv%253E%250D%250A%253C%252Fhtml%253E).

This solution is not very flexible, as it works only if the forms are directly inside a block element such as `<div>`, which in turn can only be inside other block elements. But as far as I know, this is the only (valid) way in which two forms can be in the same paragraph.